# Запуск приложения после установки автоматически, как это сделать?

Tags: java, android

Вопрос такой, как через `BroadcastReciver` сделать так, чтобы приложение стартовало автоматически после установки, нашел пример через `android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED`, но он не работает.

Comment: Боюсь вообще такое не реал сделать, а для чего такое нужно собственно?

Comment: Мне сервис в приложении запускать нужно, после установки не все нажимают открыть. Американцы говорят что можно и наглядный пример отправили кто не прав ? вы или они ?

Comment: Вопрос "Запуск приложения после установки", про сервис ничего не сказано...

Comment: @JohnStacker Android Studio это IDE и данный тег к вопросу никакого отношения не имеет. А Activity или Service имеет большое значение, т.к. первое это интерфейс, а второе фоновая работа. Если не можете правильно сформулировать вопрос тогда и ответа нормального не получите.

Answer (score 1):

1. Сервис запускается только из кода так:

   ```
   context.startService(intentToService);
   ```
2. Код может выполниться или в активити (её надо запустить вручную) или в `BroadcastReceiver`, кои прописаны в манифесте и лежат в отдельных файлах-классах. Но они зарегистрируются в системе на приём сообщений только после первого запуска приложения.

Других способов не вижу. Если вам кто-то что-то прислал - покажите, посмотрим, подумаем.